# Unset going off too early

Tags: php, session-variables, unset

The I have the following code

The problem is that the `unset($_SESSION['variable']);` is unsetting not only the whole `$_SESSION` but also stops the own if statement from running as neither the echo or function called do anything, if the unset line is removed both of those work fine.

```
if ( isset($_SESSION['variable']) ) {
    echo 'yay';
    $boxes['error'] = $this->function($_SESSION['variable']);
    unset($_SESSION['variable']);
}
```

I've never seen this before

Comment: Unset basically finishes the variable. What you should do it just remove the value. And check if the variable is empty or not.

Comment: I worked out that it was because I hadn't added the `exit();` line to the `header('location: ')` call on another page so the the Session was already being unset. So this if statement works fine now

Comment: @milky_jay: thanks for your comment. It helped me fix an issue in Wordpress where my session was unset too early as you said, because I wasn't adding `exit();` after `wp_safe_redirect`. Maybe this also helps someone :).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['variable']) ) {
    echo 'yay';
    $boxes['error'] = $this->function($_SESSION['variable']);
    $_SESSION['variable'] = '';
}
```